# Can't update OS from 10.7.3 to Mavericks

Tags: macos, software-update

I have created a Mavericks OS bootable SD card that I am trying to get onto my Macbook pro 2011 model.

Every time I try to boot from that card using **'Option'** or by selecting to use it as t the startup disk. It just brings me back to the same old Lion 10.7 installer.

On top of that I can't get that to install either because when I try to install it I get the error message **'This item is temporarily unavailable, try again later'**

What do I do?

Comment: How do you know your USB is working? or is it SD card ?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, don't yet have the reputation to comment...

Have you tried simply copying or downloading the entire Install OS X Mavericks.app to the drive you need to update & running it from there? That's the prime update method.

Comment: I am unable to even get to the actual interface where the old OS is running enough to copy that folder over. I'm stuck between OS's in the recovery mode of Lion with a mavericks bootable SD Card